# P/Invoke: OREnumValue returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c#, winapi, runtime-error, registry, pinvoke

I'm in the process of writing a basic .NET wrapper for the unmanaged [Offline Registry Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/offline-registry-library-portal). Currently, I'm working to implement a class, OfflineRegistryKey, which is modelled on [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=net-6.0) but intended for use with offline Registry Hives rather than the live system Registry.

While trying to implement an equivalent to the [GetValueNames()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames?view=net-6.0) method, which enumerates values within a Registry key, I ran into some trouble trying to P/Invoke the unmanaged function [OREnumValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/orenumvalue) from Offreg.dll. The only parameter I'm interested in in this case is the name of the value, or `lpValueName`.

My P/Invoke code for OREnumValue:

```csharp
[DllImport("Offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern uint OREnumValue(
    SafeRegistryHandle Handle,
    uint dwIndex,
    IntPtr lpValueName,
    ref uint lpcValueName,
    IntPtr lpType,
    IntPtr lpData,
    ref uint lpcbData);
```

I call the function like this in my code:

```csharp
public class OfflineRegistryKey : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SafeRegistryHandle hKey;

    public string[] GetValueNames()
    {
        uint dwIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            uint lpcValueName = 0;
            uint lpcbData = 0;

            uint returnValue = OREnumValue(hKey, dwIndex, IntPtr.Zero, ref lpcValueName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref lpcbData);
            if (returnValue == 0x0103) // ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (returnValue == 0x00EA) // ERROR_MORE_DATA
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(returnValue);
            }

            dwIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, The call to OREnumKey would return `0xEA` (ERROR_MORE_DATA), after which it would be called again until it reaches the end index and returns `0x103` (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS).

The return value I'm getting (which throws an exception at runtime and halts execution on the first iteration of the loop) is `0x57` (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), which leads me to believe that I've somehow screwed up the P/Invoke call. I would very much appreciate if someone with a greater knowledge of P/Invoke and the Windows API could provide me with some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: All definitions are available here: https://github.com/LordMike/OffregLib/blob/master/OffregLib/OffregNative.cs not sure you can pass IntPtr.Zero for lpValueName parameter.

Comment: Agreed, you should probably make it `[Out] StringBuilder lpValueName` and pass a StringBuilder of 16383 characters (although value names are not normally larger than 260, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits)

Comment: @SimonMourier this is just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your P/Invoke declaration is not correct, because `lpValueName` does not accept `NULL` [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/orenumvalue#parameters).

It's also defined as Unicode, so you should specify that.

```cs
[DllImport("Offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern uint OREnumValue(
    SafeRegistryHandle Handle,
    uint dwIndex,
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder lpValueName,
    ref uint lpcValueName,
    IntPtr lpType,
    IntPtr lpData,
    ref uint lpcbData);
```

Then you simply pass a pre-assigned buffer. Theoretically [it could be 16383 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits), you could use [`ORQueryInfoKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/orqueryinfokey) to get the max size, or just allocate the whole thing. I suggest you allocate it only once, outside the loop.

```
public string[] GetValueNames()
{
    const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
    const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 0x103;
    const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 0x00EA;
    uint dwIndex = 0;
    string lpValueName = new StringBuilder(16384);
    while (true)
    {
        uint lpcValueName = 0;
        uint lpcbData = 0;

        uint returnValue = OREnumValue(hKey, dwIndex, IntPtr.Zero, ref lpcValueName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref lpcbData);
        if (returnValue == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (returnValue == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
        {
            // Do stuff...
        }
        else if (returnValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(returnValue);
        }

        dwIndex++;
    }
}
```